# Why do people use buttons and other HTML inputs?

Tags: jquery, web-deployment

With the exception of the text input box, I can't understand why anyone would want to use an HTML input.

It's a nightmare trying to style them in all browsers, and it's much easier to style a normal div like a button, and then utilise jquery's onClick function.

Like this:
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/)

```
$('.clickme').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({"color":"#e8a010","font-size":"52pt"}, 1000);
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({"color":"#fff","font-size":"13px"}, 1000);
});
```

Why do people use buttons and then try to style them when they can just style a div normally? Is there some advantage? Am I missing something?

Comment: Fallback would be my initial answer.  If your fancy styling isn't going to work in my IE5, then at least you know a button will.

Comment: You can use HTML inputs without javascript! Your option would block out non-JS users.

Comment: agree, as of today, the need for those HTML inputs has strongly diminsihed. some libraries depend on those controls, like validation. but one can really mind them often.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Accessibility mostly. `button` and `input` elements can be given the focus by using <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and then interacted with via the keyboard. A `div` styled as a button will never receive focus via tabbing.

Whilst this behaviour is not impossible to mimic with non-form elements, you get it for free with them.

Comment: Seems to be a bug in Stack Overflow. I can't +1 this enough. People tend to forget that a massive proportion of internet users rely heavily on accessibility features of websites.

Answer (score 3):

There is accessibility and more broadly compatibility. What happens if you have JavaScript disabled? your "button" does nothing, whereas the native button functionality would still fire